# Why does GNU Image Manipulation Program open every single startup after using it once on openSUSE? How do I fix it?

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, gimp

I used GNU Image Manipulation Program (GIMP) once last week. Now every time I boot up openSUSE, it launches GIMP! I close it, but it's annoying. Why does it do this and how can I fix it? Is there some master list of apps/processes/whatever that have registered themselves to respawn across reboots or something, where I could find and clear things like this?

I guess reinstalling it would probably work, but that's pretty lame if I have to uninstall & reinstall a program every single time I want to use it, unless I plan to have it always running

Comment: Are you sure you actually quit from program and not just closed a window?

Comment: I quit using the gui rather than by, e.g. `pkill -9 [name_of_binary]` so I can't be 100% sure how it interpreted me trying to close it. Is there a config file I could look at to see any programs that are being preserved across boots as still running/background processes/whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if your desktop environment is saving the open applications and restores them on the next login.

As an arbitrary example, this is what [xfce's session manager](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/preferences) can do:

[image: XFCE session manager configuration - General settings]

you can also check (and configure) if any additional applications are started automatically, and modify that list:

[image: XFCE session manager configuration - Autostart settings]

Other desktop environments offer similar ways to set this up, so you should check the [documentation for your KDE](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/index.html) - I'm not using that, so I can't really be more specific.

Comment: thanks! I found similar options under Configure Desktop => Startup & Shutdown => Desktop Session => On Login, which I set to 'Start with an empty session'

pretty sure that's gonna do it